# Insanely slow building after upgrading new Firebase package in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I recently upgraded my Firebase package in Xcode, but the building time became much slower than before either plus extra 7 seconds or above. I tested with small projects, but got the same results.

The building process is more than 17,000/17,000 files even for the small projects.

Is this the usual?

```
[Packages][1]
```

Comment: which packages are you using ?

Comment: I'm using firestore and auth. It's fixed after I resolved the packages.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions for this case:

1. Click on the Package Dependencies at the main screen -> Resolve Package Versions.
2. If the first solution does not work, click on your project, and go to Package Dependencies. Re-add the package "firebase-ios-sdk 9.0.0 - Next Major" via https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.